# Quando edito uma planilha com pyexcel ela perde a aparencia

Tags: python

Olá, quando tento adicionar novos valores em uma planilha `ods` ela perde todo o "estilo" dela e fica só com os valores. Segue o codigo:

```
import pyexcel

sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name="dados.ods")
sheet.row += [0, 0, 0]
sheet.save_as("example_series_filter.ods")
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas como disse perco a aparencia da planilha
PS: uso python3 e tenhos as bibliotecas devidamente instaladas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está na descrição do pacote  PyExcel -

> Known constraints:
>
> Fonts, colors and charts are not supported.

Ou seja, esse pacote, embora conveniente, atualmente simplesmente descarta
as informações de aparência da planilha.

Pode ser que você ache um outro pacote que preserve as informações - mas
infelizmente, apesar de existirem outros pacotes, o foco ao manipualr planilhas sempre é chegar nos números - e qualquer coisa vale para a aparência.

Uma coisa que provavelmente funcionaria aí é você manipualr manualmetne algusn aspectos do arquivo ODS  - o ODS, assim como o XLSX são arquivos do tipo "zip" com arquivos XML e imagens agregadas lá dentro.  Esses pacoes, em Python usa a `ziplib` e ferramentas de xml do próprio Python para manipular os essas planilhas. A lógica complicada é como manter a estrutura desses XML onde estão os dados.

Agora, se você lsiatr o conteúdo de um arquivo ods com uma ferramenta como "unzip", vai ver vários arquivos .xml lá dentro. *Parte* da informação de formatação so arquivo .ods está nos outros arquivos .xml - enquanto que o conteúdo numérico em si sempre está no arquivo  `content.xml`. O pacote pyexcel provavelmente simplesmente recria todo o  aruqivo `ODS` do zero, e assim cria os outros xml (`styles.xml`,  `meta.xml) , etc...) em branco ou ocm o mínimo possível de conteúdo para serem válidos.

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma - não vou colocar o código Python completo por que me precisaria fazer uns testes e daria bastante trabalho (lembre-se que as respostas aqui são sempre voluntárias)  - mas você tem como ir fazendo aí - fazendo os testes no modo interativo mesmo

- copiar o arquivo .ods para outro, criando um backup (use o módulo
  shutil do Python)
- manipular o arquivo original como pyexcel exatamente como está fazendo agora
- usar a ziplib do Python para pegar o arquivo `contents.xml`  dentro do arquivo gravado pelo pyexcel, e coloca-lo dentro do arquivo copiado no primeiro passo.

Pronto - pelo menos algumas informações de estilo - as que não estão diretamente inline no contents.xml vão ser preservadas.
(O problema é que na minha experiência muito da informação de formatação
está dentro do contents.xml mesmo - mas se você fizer até aqui, logo começa a ter confidência o suficiente para mnipualr o xml dentro do content.xml diretamente).

Outra alternativa é usar um script Python que use o próprio LibreOffice - nesse caso, em vez de manipular o arquivo diretamente, você usa as chamadas da API do Libreoffice (tem o nome de "PyUno") para controlar diretametne o programa, e inserir os dados numa planilha já existente. O Libreoffice, claor, tem suporte completo a todas as funcionalidades de planilha - nao só formatação, como gráficos, etc...e preservaria qualquer coisa em que você não mexer.